# How to ignore group columns using Primefaces toggler

Tags: primefaces

I have such toggler in dataTable with group columns:

```html
<p:dataTable id="tbl">
    <f:facet name="header">
 <p:commandButton id="toggler_trigger" type="button"/>
 <p:columnToggler id="column_toggler" datasource="tbl" trigger="toggler_trigger">
     <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{viewModel.onToggle}" />
 </p:columnToggler>
    </f:facet>
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
 <p:row>
     <p:column colspan="3" headerText="group of 3 columns" />
 </p:row>
 <p:row>
     <p:column headerText="1 column" />
            <p:column headerText="2 column" />
            <p:column headerText="3 column" />
 </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>
    <p:column>
 <h:outputText value="value 1" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
 <h:outputText value="value 2" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
 <h:outputText value="value 3" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

How could I exclude group column with name "group of 3 columns" from toggler list? I want it consist only from three usual columns with colspan 1.

Comment: checked the docs (page 112 of the 6.2 docs) and tried using code completion in an IDE to see if there is an attribute that does exclude columns. Might work for columngroups too

Comment: Thank you, I added 'toggleable="false"' and it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `p:column` has a `toggleable` attribute which you can set to `false` to have a column not show up in the toggler. See page 112 of the 6.2 docs. It might very well also work for a `p:columnGroup` (although the documentation does not state this)

Comment: how do you hide or display two grouped columns in one toggle?